# How to place a TextView next to a button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I have a `MainActivity` initially empty. When I click on the "plus" button, you open a `DialogFragment` where there are two buttons("cancel" and "continue") and a `EditText`. In `EditText` you can write the name of the project (project 1 in this case) and by clicking "continue" you can create at run time the "Project 1", a "play" button and a `TextView` "hello" placed as shown in the image below.

I would like the `TextView` "hello" was positioned next to the "play" button on the same line.

[image]

Here is my code:

Method of the button "continue":

```
    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) { 
        EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.project_name);
        String projectName = editText.getText().toString();

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp1.gravity = Gravity.END;

        Button projectButton = new Button(this);
            projectButton.setText(projectName);
            projectButton.setLayoutParams(lp1);
            projectButton.setOnClickListener(projectListener);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp2.gravity = Gravity.START;
            lp2.setMarginStart(10); 

        Button playButton = new Button(this);
            playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button_green);
            playButton.setLayoutParams(lp2);

        TextView buttonView = new TextView(this);
            buttonView.setText("Hello");

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_row);
            linearLayout.addView(projectButton);
            linearLayout.addView(playButton);
            linearLayout.addView(buttonView);
    }
```

`MainActivity` XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" > 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The whole layout must be created dynamically and then using java code not XML.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Change android:orientation="vertical" to android:orientation="horizontal" for your LinearLayout with id=button_row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `Button` and `TextView` inside `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"`

```
 LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
 ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
 ll.addView(playButton);
 ll.addView(buttonView);

 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_row);
 linearLayout.addView(projectButton);
 linearLayout.addView(ll);
```

Comment: I cannot...I need 15 reputation to vote up your answer

Comment: I posted another question..can you have a look at that one? tnx

Answer (score 2):

by using horizontal android:orientation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textView" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using Button and Text View you can use a single button also.

```
 Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );    
 Button playButton = new Button(this); 
 playButton.setText("Hello"); 
 playButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null ); 
 playButton.setLayoutParams(lp2);
```

now you will get a button with text and icon on its left.